# Drupal Webform Report

Tags: drupal, drupal-webform

I have deleted one of my content from my Drupal site of WEB form content type.

Now I need to retrieve its report.

Please guide me on how to retrieve the report or database of a deleted web form.

Thanks in advance,

Anamika.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Assumption that this is about Drupal 8 since this is not mentioned in the OP's question.

I am afraid you can't retrieve data from your webform once it's deleted. When you deleted the webform you expliytidly confirmed that you're okay with the deletion and all its related data.

[image]

If you happen to have a database backup, there is some hope to retrieve the data. Webform data is spread over multiple tables, here are the most important ones:

- `webform`: List of all your webforms and their ID
- `webform_submission`: List of all submissions (1 line per submission)
- `webform_submission_data`: List of all your fields & values for a submission

So if you have a database backup, you can probably retrieve all the `sid` (submission id's) from `webform_submission` for the deleted webform and then retrieve all the data then in the `webform_submission_data` table.

If you don't have any kind of database back-up, I am afraid your data is lost forever.